# how to set contenttype in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, multipart, contenttype

Here i need to set `contenttype="multipart/form-data"` while form submit but its fail it's assign `contenttype="text/html"` how to change?

```
refButton = '<form id="importForm" action="http://localhost:8080/bwsim/UploadScenario" class="userInputForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
         '<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />' +
         '</form>';
         document.getElementById("popupDiv").innerHTML = refButton;
         $("#popupDiv").dialog({
             title: "Import Scenario",
             draggable: true,
             bgiframe: true,
             modal: true,
             width: 500,
             heigth: 100,
             show: {effect: 'blind', duration: 500},
             hide: {effect: 'fade', duration: 1000},
             zIndex: 1000,
             buttons: {
                 'Upload': function() {
                     if ($("#importForm").valid()) {
                         document.forms["importForm"].submit();
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                      }
                 },
                 'Cancel': function() {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
             }
         });
```

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't misdiagnosing the problem? Browsers don't support sending `text/html` requests (unless you use XMLHttpRequest). The `text/html` document is probably what the server is responding with. Or are you talking about the content type of the document you pick with the file input (so you have a multi-part request and on the parts is text/html)?

Comment: @Quentin can u explain?

Comment: No. I don't understand what your problem is. That's why I'm asking you questions in an effort to get you to explain what you think is going wrong. Tell us what behaviour you expect. Tell us what behaviour you want. Tell us why you want that behaviour. Tell us what tools you are using to determine what the content type you are talking about is. Quote from those tools with sufficient context that we can understand what is going on.

Comment: @Quentin Actually my problem i need to upload some file. so i set contenttype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @quentin but its fail it assign contenttype="text/html" this format

Comment: As I said before: **How can you tell**? What tool are you using to determine the content type?

Comment: i check in google chrome F12

Comment: Where, precisely are you looking? Show us a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62982/discussion-between-javasundaram-and-quentin).

Comment: @Quentin are u there?

Comment: You're making a GET request. The request doesn't have Content-Type: text/html. There's no content-type there at all!

Comment: @Quentin it's ok how to send request like Content-Type:"multipart/form-data" i'm struggle since morning

Comment: You have to make a POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its fail it's assign contenttype="text/html" how to change?

No, it isn't.

Your form doesn't have a `method` attribute, so it is defaulting to GET.

GET requests don't have request bodies, so there is no content to describe the content-type of.

Add `method="POST"` to your form start tag.